# Передача функции в другой поток Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, многопоточность, асинхронность

При попытке передачи функции в другой поток, она исчезает, а с другими объектами всё работает исправно.

```
import threads from 'threads'

const spawn = threads.spawn;
const thread = spawn(function () {
});


export default function (data, refreshF, sendF) {
funcs = {refreshF, sendF};
console.log(funcs); //вывод: {refreshF: [Function], sendF: [Function]}
thread
    .run(function doThis(input, done) {
        console.log('---');
        console.log(funcs); //вывод: {data: {...(вывод правильный)}, funcs: {}}
        console.log('---');
    }).send({data, funcs});
}
```

Comment: Потому что нельзя передать функцию. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm  `Error and Function objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone`